# Как создать базу данных для контента в MySQl?

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите или приведите пример как создать базу данных для товаров которые делятся на разделы и категории. К примеру есть раздел "ОДЕЖДА" в этом разделе скажем две категории "БРЮКИ" и "РУБАШКИ" а в этих категориях товары!

Comment: можно в таблице категорий ввести доп поле "parent_id", например, и в нём хранить id родительской категории, по умолчанию оно будет равно null

Comment: Я правильно понимаю если категория  "РУБАШКИ" то "parent_id" "ОДЕЖДА"?

Comment: нет, parent_id - это id поле категории "ОДЕЖДА"

Answer (score 0):

Я могу предложить такой вариант:

```
create table types (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(255)
);

insert into types (title) values ('Одежда');

create table categories (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
    type_id int,
    title varchar(255),
    foreign key (type_id) references types(id)
); 

insert into categories (type_id, title) values (1, 'Брюки'), (1, 'Рубашки');

create table goods (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
    category_id int,
    title varchar(255),
    foreign key goods_category (category_id) references categories(id)
); 

insert into goods (category_id, title) values (1, 'Брюки мужские'), (2, 'Рубашка поло спорт');


select 
  goods.id,
  types.title as type,
  categories.title as category,
  goods.title
from goods
join categories on goods.category_id = categories.id
join types on categories.type_id = types.id
;
```

[запустить SQL](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=4e5791625f32e93039cf8d77ff8f6e3d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)